# How to convert java arraylist to json array store data using java and jsp and extjs

Tags: java, jsp, extjs3

is there any way to convert array list to json store input data using jsp and java for extjs.
means i need to get data for json store from jsp page and java arraylis

Comment: I have tried some thing like json_encode(arraylist) it showing error in jsp

Comment: Did you try to use [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) for converting the array list ?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go hope this helps you... Here im getting state values from db..

```
                    String response = "id,State#";
        List stateList = new ArrayList<>();

        //DB call

        for (int i = 0; i < stateList.size(); i++) {
            response += stateList.get(i).gets_code() + ",";
            response += stateList.get(i).getS_name() + "#";
        }
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(response , "|");
        String finalMsg = null;
        String str1 = null;
        while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
            String token = st.nextToken();
            finalMsg = token;
        }
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
        stbuffer.append("{\"root\":[");
        String[] data = finalMsg.split("#");
        int len = data.length;
        String[] headings = data[0].split(",");
        for (int x = 1; x < len; x++) {
            String[] data1 = data[x].split(",");
            int len1 = data1.length;
            for (int y = 0; y < len1; y++) {
                object.put(headings[y], data1[y]);

            }
        stbuffer.append(object);
        stbuffer.append(",");

        }
        stbuffer.append("]}");
        String result = stbuffer.toString();
        result = result.replace(",]", "]");
```